# Java interface naming agreements

Tags: java, interface

I need help. I have an interface with only one method in it:

```
getLanguages();
```

Classes that implement this interface should implement the `getLanguages()` method to return a list of supported languages. But i don't know how to title this interface to be clear and simple. "LangGetter"? "LangListGetter"? Are there any interface naming agreements?

Comment: What do the classes do, apart from holding a list of supported languages? Translate? Talk? Write? etc...

Comment: This class holds configuration settings and language list i some of them.

Comment: Consider getting the book "[Code Complete](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670)" since it is an excellent book on the philosophy, theory and practice of writing programs and goes into quite a bit of depth on this very subject of identifier naming.

Comment: You do not need to create a new interface.  `java . util . concurrent . Callable < ? extends Iterable < ? extends Language > >` will do.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, it's a brilliant book and i read it.

Comment: @emory I don't really get it, can you elaborate?

Comment: @maba `Callable` is an already existing generic interface with one method `T call ( ) throws Exception` where `T` is a generic parameter.  Thus `Callable<Iterable<Language>>` has only one method `Iterable<Language> call ( ) throws Exception`.  It is identical to the psed's interface except (1) the method name and (2) it allows for Exceptions where psed's method does not.

Answer (score 2):

According to this article on [Using Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm):

> Interfaces: Names should be in CamelCase. They tend to have a name that describes an operation that a class can do:
>
> ```
> interface Comparable
> interface Enumerable
> ```
>
> Note that some programmers like to distinguish interfaces by beginning the name with an "I":
>
> ```
> interface IComparable
> interface IEnumerable
> ```

So according to those conventions, you could give it a nice, simple name such as `ISupportedLanguages`.

Comment: Yes, the C# naming guidelines specifically require the `I`, while Java's do not. So including the `I` in my suggested name is just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

How about ILanguageAware or just LanguageAware.

Comment: In the current state, this post should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces names should express capability, like `Comparable`. You should identify what capability you want the users of your interface to have. I.e: `LanguageSupporter` or `HasLanguages`.